# Submit form after ajax returns

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

When a user submits a form I want ajax to check if the email address exists using the following

```
$.post("checkemail.php", {email: email})
```

Depending on the value I will choose to submit or not (preventdefault)

However the form is submitting before returning the value.
I have tried the following:

```
$.when($.post("inc/checkemail.php", {email: email})).done(function(result) {
 // code here
}
```

However I can't seem to get this right. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance, you guys are always great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stopping the default behavior should always happen regardless of what the post returns. Only on 'done' should you decide to submit the form:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault()
  $.post('checkemail.php', {email: email})
  .done( function(result){
    // check response to see if the email does not exist
    $('form').off('submit') // We don't want to stop the submission anymore.
    $('form').submit()
  })
})
```

**edit:** Also, note that $.post returns a type of deferred object, so the $.when call is unnecessary.

Comment: This works but if I use this when trying to execute $('form').submit() it prevents it from submitting due to the on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

But it has pointed me in the right direction! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Heh. right. You would want to remove the handler before submitting. $('form').off('submit'); $('form').submit();

Answer (score 1):

Put the code that depends on the response from `checkmail.php` in the `$.post` callback:

```
$.post("checkemail.php", {email: email}, function(result){
    // "result" = response from checkmail.php
    ...
});
```

Cheers

Comment: You beat me with 1 minute because I wanted to add a link to the docs... +1.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I needed to preventdefault first as mentioned by jhummel as it was submitting before running this

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is any different than using the OPs deferred object approach. The problem seems to be he's not stopping the default behavior before issuing the request.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. @Carlos13 was writing his comment at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("checkemail.php", {email: email}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // this gets executed when the AJAX has finished and had succes.
});
```

Straight from the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

Comment: How's that different than my answer?

Comment: @Madbreaks Not, but I didn't see it while writing mine.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I needed to preventdefault first as mentioned by jhummel as it was submitting before running this